How to make a div appear on specific Days and also be able to close/hide the div
I need to make a div/message only appear on MONDAY, TUESDAY, and WEDNSEDAY using html, css, and javascript and also add a X button to be closed.
This is my Html
<div class="header">
    <div id="banner" class="banner" role="alert">
        <p>Attend the Chamber of Commerce meet and greet  on Wednesday at 7:00 p.m.</p>
        <button id="closeBanner" class="close-button" aria-label="Close">×</button>
    </div>
</div>


What have you tried? Look into the various JavaScript date and day functions and have a go at coding this. If still stuck, put the code into your question with a description of what isn't working and any error messages.

You can use the class Date:
const now = new Date();
let day = now.getDay(); 

Where it will return a number between 0-6 starting from Sunday
To achive that you can use JS where the div banner will be hidden by default and onload the window will check if the day is one of the list you mention above and show it if true.
window.addEventListener("load", (event) => {
const now = new Date();
const day = now.getDay(); 
// 2 = monday, 4 = widnesday
if (day >= 1 && day <= 3){
  document.querySelector("#post-editor-78687221").style.display = "block"
 }
});

while the html will be:
<div class="header">
    <div id="banner" class="banner" role="alert" style="display: none;">
        <p>Attend the Chamber of Commerce meet and greet  on Wednesday at 7:00 p.m.</p>
        <button id="closeBanner" class="close-button" aria-label="Close">×</button>
    </div>
</div>


This does not work for me - in my system weeks start on a Sunday.

Sorry, I updated the answer it starts from Sunday not Saterday

And if you want to change the days you only have to change this condition day >= 1 && day <= 3
